# Writing PDF content in Response

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, itext, response

I am writing PDF byte array in response but when I download the file, its showing blank. Means no content. Here what I have tried. How to resolve that. I have written following servlet to read pdf file and then send that pdf file as response but I am getting blank PDF.

```
    @WebServlet("/downloadTest")
public class TestServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        performTask(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        performTask(request, response);
    }

    private void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        File pdfFile = new File("D://Tempo.pdf");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Tempo");
        response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
        OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int bytes;
        while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

I am getting something like below in response.

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
3 0 obj
<</Length 708/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xTMSÛ0½ûWèHQµú´nup¡ÍôI;Ð3þ}%%4v¼pÈLF»zoßê=?'ã2¥I¹Lò¾FÊ_ÉAFNªü¨%¹ÌÈ²¾}y¬Zú¥üí®°ÍMú?2¹JÃSw~0ªÈ_Ï¢­!J!IS%ÅæÜ2ü¤ZàãÁ"ÜBGÈ%DÈ¥+#wÜFùs×±£;ºÑ×n¬t£!ºÑÝ8ÑJàº±ó -xÝX!èÆ
A7ZÐò -èyÐÝ/\ù0ñ"uçÆáÝ8ÝÖ/Omó:¿ðáykV@ æl6ñE¤å4Þb¹lªÕj~>íSÔ-á
ñb2!$Hý)Le)S]L>ÄäSc1Ý÷­ÍºÕÛ)Õ\ÉÈ/í]Ý8ÀaÔn'ÄÖ(ÀÍ½ËpÒÅ`©°[¼lz jIqG÷(´ 2t\'ó<+{© Ú¸o-ErkøY×vV"ÿh%Òµà.oÆ=<#ÖV]Ow>-¼^Gú·ùKQqCD¬ÚE[­v$(ùá«*6ù\4"'6N/òiIR®\¿îwgy~=)y?I<ôº'^e)ÝRéd$J(äÉlg½WáÒ-`cAÒ¶¢³E{÷Jûªi»¥þû»;ÄYñí¬ ß{Îåöÿ3,(è¹Ï{:>â±¦Ê%v«8<½Ä¬6sÆÔ¥P<¬nxéøæ4»^G5û~ÊlZîo6¥ö2Û^³u!ß1Û2j¶
 j6ÍÙ+WMKÆ>äq«íµÚfÕì`-ûÈjÃ[ïXmØ¼ÕúVû(@qQ
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Resources<</Font<</F1 1 0 R/F2 2 0 R>>>>/Contents 3 0 R/Parent 4 0 R>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Bold/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Roman/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[5 0 R]>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 4 0 R>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Producer(iText® 5.5.10 ©2000-2015 iText Group NV \(AGPL-version\))/CreationDate(D:20170615141342+05'30')/ModDate(D:20170615141342+05'30')/Author(KSHITIJ)/Creator(Rishabh Software)/Title(Title)/Subject(Subject)>>
endobj
xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000911 00000 n 
0000001000 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000001090 00000 n 
0000000790 00000 n 
0000001141 00000 n 
0000001186 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 8/Root 6 0 R/Info 7 0 R/ID [<8fa4882fe3f73b7d1a30457c18d686a4><8fa4882fe3f73b7d1a30457c18d686a4>]>>
%iText-5.5.10
startxref
1416
%%EOF
```

Comment: Did you try writing something else, like "foo bar" to test your writer?

Comment: Yes. I am able to write CSV same way. I am just changing content type and bytes for PDF file writing.

Comment: What you get looks like an OK PDF file to me. The header is correct, it has an OK xref table, and it has an EOF marker. However: it seems that your browser doesn't know what to do with files with the MIME-Type `"application/pdf"`, Have you tried with another browser that is smarter than the one you are currently using?

Comment: @Bruno I am using Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit). I have tried with Opera. It has same result. File size is same as the I am reading file. Its just get white I dont understand whats happening.

Comment: It is normal that the PDF doesn't open in the browser, because you are serving it as an attachment: `"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Tempo"` You have to save the file, and then open it *with a PDF viewer!* The code that you see, is a valid PDF document, opened in a plain text viewer, or in a tool that doesn't know how to render PDF. Do you have Adobe Reader or a similar PDF viewer?

Comment: That response is from Browser. I already tried to opening in Adobe Reader but its the same. Blank. :(

Comment: Are you sure that the original file is not also broken?

Comment: I am 100% sure. As I am opening in Adobe reader it displays all content as expected.

Comment: Could you solve it?

Comment: @beso9595 Currently I just tested that code and its working fine. The question I posted at that time resources I was using was different like different tomcat or something different. Currently Its working with Java8, Tomcat 9, servlet version 3.1.0 and commons-fileupload 1.3.1. I have also updated "Tempo" to pdfFile.getName(). Hope this will help.